# Check if current user is a member of exchange distribution list - Outlook C#

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to find out if current Outlook user is a member of particular exchange distribution list. If he is, then he should see child form and if he isn't; then he should see message box.

My following code is working up to the point, if user is a member of DistList, he get child form but I don't know how to check show him message box if he isn't member.

```
                string UserName = (string)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.Name;
                string PersonalPublicFolder = "Public Folders - " + application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
                Outlook.MAPIFolder contactsFolder = outlookNameSpace.Folders[PersonalPublicFolder].Folders["Favorites"];

                Outlook.DistListItem addressList = contactsFolder.Items["ContactGroup"];

                if (addressList.MemberCount != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= addressList.MemberCount; i++)
                    {
                        Outlook.Recipient recipient = addressList.GetMember(i);
                        string contact = recipient.Name;
                        if (contact == UserName)
                        {
                                var assignOwnership = new AssignOwnership();
                                assignOwnership.Show();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to process a DL in your Contacts folder? or a DL from Exchange GAL?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Dist list from Exchange GAL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetMemberOfList()` - it will return `AddressEntries` object that contains all DLs that the user is a member of.

Be prepared to handle nulls and errors.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, much appreciated.